# ABP: How to re- load Localization text dynamically without restarting API app

Tags: asp.net-core, localization, aspnetboilerplate, abp

I am using ABP v4.7.0 (.NET CORE 2.1) with angular client.
I built some custom localization providers. These providers get translation dictionaries from Azure Blob Storage. I add localization sources on startup with these providers.

```
localizationConfiguration.Sources.Add(
                new DictionaryBasedLocalizationSource(InductothermMVPConsts.LocalizationSourceName,
                    new BlobEmbeddedFileLocalizationDictionaryProvider(
                        typeof(InductothermMVPLocalizationConfigurer).GetAssembly(),
                        "InductothermMVP.Core.Localization.SourceFiles"
                    )
                )
            );
```

On StartUp, I call this method and localization dictionaries are built correctly.

Now, I created one api endpoint which will update data in Azure Blob Storage, after files are updated, I am again initializing the dictionaries

```
public class BlobEmbeddedFileLocalizationDictionaryProvider : LocalizationDictionaryProviderBase
    {
#pragma warning disable GCop406 //  Mark {0} field as read-only.
        private const int Count = 50;
#pragma warning restore GCop406 //  Mark {0} field as read-only.
        private readonly Assembly _assembly;
        private readonly string _rootNamespace;

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new <see cref="BlobEmbeddedFileLocalizationDictionaryProvider"/> object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="assembly">Assembly that contains embedded xml files</param>
        /// <param name="rootNamespace">Namespace of the embedded xml dictionary files</param>
        public BlobEmbeddedFileLocalizationDictionaryProvider(Assembly assembly, string rootNamespace)
        {
            _assembly = assembly;
            _rootNamespace = rootNamespace;
            InitializeDictionaries();
        }

        protected void InitializeDictionaries()
        {
            var sourceName = "XXXXXX";
            var allCultureInfos = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnection"]);

            var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("xxxxxx");
            var res = container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            var count = BlobEmbeddedFileLocalizationDictionaryProvider.Count;
            var listBlobs = container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(null, true, BlobListingDetails.None, count, null, null, null).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            foreach (var item in listBlobs.Results)
            {
                var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(((Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob)item).Name);
                string path = _assembly.Location.Replace("xxxxx", "");
                path += ((Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob)item).Name;
                blockBlob.DownloadToFileAsync(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
                {
                    var xmlString = Utf8Helper.ReadStringFromStream(stream);
                    InitializeDictionary(CreateXmlLocalizationDictionary(xmlString), isDefault: ((CloudBlob)item).Name.EndsWith(sourceName + ".xml"));
                }
            }
        }

        protected virtual XmlLocalizationDictionary CreateXmlLocalizationDictionary(string xmlString)
        {
            return XmlLocalizationDictionary.BuildFomXmlString(xmlString);
        }
        protected void InitializeDictionary<TDictionary>(TDictionary dictionary, bool isDefault = false)
            where TDictionary : ILocalizationDictionary
        {
           if (Dictionaries.ContainsKey(dictionary.CultureInfo.Name))
            {
                throw new AbpInitializationException(SourceName + " source contains more than one dictionary for the culture: " + dictionary.CultureInfo.Name);
            }

            Dictionaries[dictionary.CultureInfo.Name] = dictionary;

            if (isDefault)
            {
                if (DefaultDictionary != null)
                {
                    throw new AbpInitializationException("Only one default localization dictionary can be for source: " + SourceName);
                }

                DefaultDictionary = dictionary;
            }
        }
    }
    internal static class Utf8Helper
    {
        public static string ReadStringFromStream(Stream stream)
        {
            var bytes = stream.GetAllBytes();
            var skipCount = HasBom(bytes) ? 3 : 0;
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, skipCount, bytes.Length - skipCount);
        }

        private static bool HasBom(byte[] bytes)
        {
            if (bytes.Length < 3)
            {
                return false;
            }

if (!(bytes[0] == 0xEF && bytes[1] == 0xBB && bytes[2] == 0xBF))
{
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

This Provider is executed as expected.
But When I Refresh my client(Angular) Application, **I still see the old Translations.**

If I restart my API application, new translations are reflected correctly.

Can someone help me to understand, what am I missing here.

Thanks for the help in advance.